# Excel - lookup between two dates and return a pre determined value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following time frames which has a "Y" or "N" beneath them.

[image]

I then have a list of dates, by day, vertically as per below.  Next to each date I would like to put a "Y" or "N" in the adjacent column based on whether that date falls between the dates mentioned above.  In the example below the answer is typed manually but would like a formula to calculate this.

[image]

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should change your format to the picture I added below. By doing this, you can apply the formula I wrote to B5 cell. Then you can use flash fill property to find the predetermined values of every single date below.

If you face any problem, we can contact again. Have a nice day.

[image: solution]

Comment: Apologies ceo, i did not understand any of that.  Changing the date format would not be useful as it will confuse the end user.  I will see if copying out your formula still works.  You also lost me on "flash fill property.

Comment: Hey, I didn't suggest you to change date format. I only said that you should arrange their locations according to the pic i attacted. Otherwise the formula won't work (e.g. "1/27/2021" should be written on A1 cell). Plus, I tried to say that you should copy and paste the formula to all cells you want to apply. "Flash fill" meant to that copy-paste process. I hope everything is clear now, good luck :)